# How to resize a plot?

Tags: plotting

*After* the plot is drawn I can change its dimension using the mouse. Is it possible to specify the dimension of the plot *before* it is drawn?

I am looking for something like

```
Plot[fun[x],{x,xmin,xmax},Dimesion->{xpoints, ypoints}]
```

I know about `ImageSize`, but I want to specify the x and y points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `AspectRatio -> Full` to have the graphic stretched to fill the rectangle specified  with the option `ImageSize -> {xpoints, ypoints}`:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}, ImageSize -> {600, 100}, AspectRatio -> Full]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To set the size of the image canvas you can use

```
ImageSize -> {xpoints, ypoints}.
```

This may not do what you intend, as it will just add white space to fill out the figure to the aspect ratio set by `{xpoints, ypoints}`. To change the aspect ratio of the plotted regio use the `AspectRatio` option.